# Java getNode after transforming xml with xslt

Tags: java, xml, dom, xslt

I need to ask how i can get nodes of xml atfer transforming xml file with xslt using java transform factory.

when do transform without java my document looks like i need. But when i transform using java  it looks like xslt don't change anything just remove nodes and return everthing in plain text.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    db.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {

        @Override
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
            return null;
        }
    });

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("pathtoxsl"));

    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement()), new StreamResult(outputStream));
    System.out.println(outputStream.toString());
```

Can anyone help my?

/****new problem *****/
i CHANGE to DOMResult but now i get null pointer exception. in the following line:
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement()), outputStream);

I suppose in can be problem with xslt

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1223)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1060)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1268)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1251)
    at com.atea.biztalk.tests.suppliers.invoiceimport.request.Requests.transformXML(Requests.java:166)
    at com.atea.biztalk.tests.suppliers.invoiceimport.request.Soap_SerialNumber_ACME.Run_Soap_SerialNumber_ACME(Soap_SerialNumber_ACME.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

if run succes i get in console this:

Line #0; Column #0; org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.

and get just xml version and encoding

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `StreamResult`.  Use a `DOMResult` instead, which will save the transformation output into a new DOM tree in memory.  `DOMResult#getNode()` will return the document node of the transformed output.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first parameter in transform method to StreamSource.

```
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new java.io.File("path_to_xml")), new StreamResult(outputStream));
```

I used your code snippet except for the above line for the transform and it works fine (with my sample xml and xsl files).